# Does OWASP dependency check worked on salesforce Apex class files(*.cls)

Tags: azure-devops, salesforce, pipeline, apex, owasp

I am first time using **OSASP Dependency check** using **Azure devops**. Here this check is not scanning my apex class files and xml metadata files. So I wanna confirm is it scan those or not and what type of file it scan for salesforce projects?

I tried to search from **owsap** officially site but from where it is not cleared.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand are APEX files Zipped Library which can contain Jar Files, I think it makes more sense to scan the pipeline which actually contains the code of the Apex Files.

Comment: Salesforce Apex files are plaintext, java-like language. You deploy them plaintext and SF complies them server-side, no jars in sight. You may be thinking about Oracle APEX (application express) product?

Comment: I think you are right, I googled for it and found a page with the structure of the package.